# java multi-threading data race in parallel computation

Tags: java, multithreading, computation

hey guys i am doing a undergrad math research and i wrote a java program to do lots of computation. First i need to find all the 4-elements combination out of let's say 2500(can be way more up to 300 * 300) elements, then i need to test every candidate with a list of quotientGroup(it's a class i implemented), if my candidate pasted all the quotientGroup's test, then it's one of the target i am looking for. But if the candidate failed any one of the test, i can immediately end there and test next candidate. Right now, despite my program get the correct result, it required a lots of time. So i am trying to use multithreading to solve the problem.

So this is my idea: i will partition my list of quotientGroup into 4 separate lists of quotientGroup, and test with my candidate simultaneously. In order to avoid the data race, i think i need to make 4 copies of my candidate, that's not horrible since every candidate contains only 4 elements. But the thing is if any one of the 4 threads found a failed test let's say counter-example, i need the 4 threads all shut down to avoid unnecessary further testing. But how can i achieve that? Can i make a global boolean variable called success, then if any one of the 4 threads found a counter example i will set this variable to false and i also need to add a checker in each thread if this global variable is false then i need to shut down the thread. But then i will have data race on this boolean variable and my result will be inaccurate. Am i right? Please give some advices, i am new to multithreading.

Comment: It would probably be easier to partition your 2500 combinations into several groups and use one thread per group.

Comment: It seems you think threads can't share any state because it automatically cause data race issues. That's not correct. You just need to learn how to *safely* share state. If the state is immutable, there is no problem sharing it. If the state is mutable, you need proper synchronization to access it. in the case of a single boolean variable, making it volatile or using an AtomicBoolean makes is thread-safe.

Comment: Re, "...But then i will have data race on this boolean variable and my result will be inaccurate."  Data races are not always bad.  The race between a thread setting a `stop` flag and another thread checking the flag is a perfect example.  Why do you think that that it would have any effect on the result that the first thread already found?  (P.S., It probably would make your explanation easier to follow if you would include some actual code.)

Comment: Thank you @JB Nizet, i will look over the AtomicBoolean.

Comment: @james large Thanks for the reply, i assume that the data race on boolean variable will cause inaccurate result because of this case: if one thread is checking the boolean variable but at the same time another thread found a counter example and was trying to set the variable as false, the second thread will not be able to set the boolean variable correctly because the first thread is using the same variable. Am i right?

Comment: @BYsBro, The variable should be `false` at the start, and the first thread to find a solution should set it `true.`  _No other thread should ever set it._  Threads that have not found a solution will periodically check the variable, and if they see `true`, they stop.  Otherwise they leave the variable untouched, and keep searching.

Comment: P.S.:  In order for the program to be strictly correct, the variable either should be `volatile`, or you should use an `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: @james large, Thanks again and i see your point, the thing is i need my candidate to pass all the 4 thread's tests to confirm it's a right target. So i can't end the other threads when my candidate passed one single thread. But yeah i will definitely try AtomicBoolean.